# Bootrap3 responsive navigation has stopped working on mobile & tablet screen size

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been creating a site with bootstrap3 and had the drop down menus working perfectly fine with the correct CSS styling. I've not changed any code but the mobile view and tablet view navigations now have no styling and are shown in list view only - please see: http://creative-media.info/FatLossPro/

I am unsure how this can happen i;ve not amended the code and reverted back to the last working copy. The navigation has been working fine for the last 2 weeks. I've also reuploaded the JS folder and the CSS files along with the function.php to ensure no files had mis-saved, corrupted or contain any missing elements.

any help with this bootstrap3 navigation issue in wordpress would be greatly appreciated (tablet and mobile view no longer working - no CSS styling)

Answer (score 0):

Like This media query.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Hi Piyush thanks for your information on media queries, I've already got these in place via the bootstrap theme and I had the menu fully working at all sizes correctly: mobile, tablet and desktop. The issue is the fact it no longer works? I've been examining the code in bootstrap.css against an unedited css file downloaded with the original theme and can't see any chunks of code that have been removed which would cause it to stop working?

Comment: Ok. Give me your site url.

Comment: ttp://www.creative-media.info/FatLossPro